# Gradle task to create a zip archive of a directory

Tags: gradle, zip, build.gradle, archive

I have a gradle task to create a zip archive of a directory.
The gradle task is:

```
task archiveReports(type: Zip) {
   from '/projects/Reports/*'
   archiveName 'Reports.zip'
}
```

When I am running the command 'gradle archiveReports', its showing the build is successful. However, no zip file is getting created.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I figured out a way for this: 
Its working for me now.

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {
   from 'Reports/'
   include '*'
   include '*/*' //to include contents of a folder present inside Reports directory
   archiveName 'Reports.zip'
   destinationDir(file('/dir1/dir2/dir3/'))
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to have just one include '***/*'?

Comment: You could also use ```from fileTree(dir: 'Reports')``` which would allow you to specify exclude patterns like ```excludes: ['**/dir/*', '**/R$*']``` if needed. ```from fileTree(dir: 'Reports', excludes: ['**/dir/*', '**/R$*'])``` https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:file_trees

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba You are right. it is possible with `include "**/*"` alone. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

With Kotlin DSL

```kotlin
tasks.register<Zip>("packageDistribution") {
    archiveFileName.set("my-distribution.zip")
    destinationDirectory.set(layout.buildDirectory.dir("dist"))

    from(layout.buildDirectory.dir("toArchive"))
}
```

With Groovy

```
tasks.register('packageDistribution', Zip) {
    archiveFileName = "my-distribution.zip"
    destinationDirectory = layout.buildDirectory.dir('dist')

    from layout.buildDirectory.dir("toArchive")
}
```

Taken from the [official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_archives_example)

Answer (score 12):

With **Gradle 6.7**,

```
task packageDistribution(type: Zip) {
    archiveFileName = "my-distribution.zip"
    destinationDirectory = file("$buildDir/dist")

    from "$buildDir/toArchive"
}
```

Note : archiveName is deprected.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone will come here to find out how to zip your project e.g. to use it as an AWS lambda zip, here you go:

```
tasks {
val zipTask by register("createZip", Zip::class) {
    from(processResources)
    from(compileKotlin)
    archiveFileName.set("app.zip")
    into("lib") {
        from(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    }
}

build {
    dependsOn(zipTask)
}
```

}